# The final field "" cannot be assigned, cannot figure out what is wrong

Tags: processing

So, I had some issues with this code thanks to Syntax errors etc. I have managed to eliminate the Syntax Errors but have now been greeted with "*The final field code_from_lab.Wheel.x cannot be assigned*" on my "Wheel" class.

I have tried for an hour tweaking various lines but to no avail, any help would be greatly appreciated.

The class with the error will be below and the main code has been screenshotted [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3Ge8.png)

```
[Screenshot of Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJkCC.png)

  class Wheel {

  final color Wheel = color(255, 0, 0);

  final int x = 50;
  int y;
  PImage img = loadImage("BikeWheel.png");

  Wheel(int y) {
    this.y = y;
  }

  void render() {
    image(img, x, y);
  }
  void mouseDrag() //dragging with mouse
  {
    if (mousePressed && dist(mouseX, mouseY, this.x, this.y) < 50) //mouse close to top corner?
   {
      this.x= mouseX; //move rocket to mouse position
      this.y= mouseY;
    }
  }

  boolean crash(Bike bike) {
    // return the result of checking if the plane has crashed into the bike
    return abs(this.x-bike.x) < img.width && abs(this.y - bike.y) < img.height;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Do you understand what `final` means?  `x` is declared that way, yet you are trying to assign it a value in the `mouseDrag()` method.

Comment: thank you, thats what it was. any idea why the wheel is not showing in the program?